# Setting up a DDNS behind a DDNS Server?

Tags: networking, router, dns, port-forwarding, ddns

**TLDR**; I have a working DDNS at `ddns.example.com`, I want to make it capable of routing requests such `host1.example.com` to my locally hosted machines.

So, I have a public domain at let's say `example.com` at Google Domains. I have a DDNS capable router, which let's say has a dynamic IP address that is currently set to `1.2.3.4`.

I point my router to properly recognize my GD account, and at GD, I set `ddns.example.com` to match my router. Everything works at this point, and I can see that, for instance, host1 on my local network whose port `1234` is forwarded, can be seen at `ddns.example.com:1234`.

What I instead *want* to do, is to be able to write `host1.example.com:1234/a/b?c` and get to `host1:1234/a/b?c` on my local network.

My current thinking is that this should be possible by:

1. I add a [wildcard record](https://support.google.com/domains/answer/4633759?hl=en) from `*.ddns` to `ddns.example.com` in Google Domains.
2. Add a `CNAME` from `host1` to `host1.ddns.example.com` on Google Domains.
3. Set up a dynamic DNS server+client on `host2` on my local network with port 53 with port-forwarding through my router (I have a DNS server that is capable of including the current external IP address in authoritative answers which is installed on `host2`).
4. Add the appropriate entries to my local DDNS client/server (`host2`):

   1. Add `NS` record `ns.ddns.example.com` to `host2`.
   2. Add dynamic `A` record `ns.ddns.example.com` to `host2`.
   3. Add dynamic `A` record `services.ddns.example.com` to `host2`.
5. I port-forward `1234` from `host1` on my router.

Here is what I think *should* happen:

I type in `host1.example.com/a/b?c`:

1. NS request to `com.`, `example.com.`, and then `A` request for `host1`.
2. `host1.example.com` gets redirected to `host1.ddns.example.com`
3. Client asks for `NS` record from `ddns.example.com`. Answer is `1.2.3.4`.
4. Client asks for the IP address of `host1.ddns.example.com`. Answer is `1.2.3.4`.
5. Client connects to `1.2.3.4:1234/a/b/?c` which is hosted by `host1:1234/a/b/?c`.

`dig`ing the `host1.example.com` domain does return the `CNAME` record `host1.ddns.example.com`. However, then `dig`ing `host1.ddns.example.com` returns the Google NS domains. It was my understanding that a `CNAME` record would basically mean that any request for that record would be forwarded. So I expected that doing a `dig` for the `host1.ddns.example.com` would match the wildcard, become a `CNAME` redirect to `ddns.example.com`, which in turn would be able to handle the rest of the recursion. What am I missing here?

Comment: Do you have enough public IP addresses for each host you want to give a public DNS to?  **DNS does not resolve to an IP:port, it only resolves to an IP.**

Comment: I am aware of that, and I do. I fixed my problem.

Comment: Do you have rights to `example.com` or `ddns.example.com`? It's a bit unclear at times in your question, and very important to having efficient and correct routing... Are the devices that should respond to `ddns.example.com` and `hostN.ddns.example.com` on the same network or do each have a different __external__ IP address?... I ask because I think ya may be missing that names are resolved in [reverse order](https://www.linode.com/docs/networking/dns/dns-records-an-introduction/), meaning that ya could just _hint_ where to find `*.ddns.example.com` and let your server forward beyond that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problem by examining each piece in isolation and determining that they were working correctly. The problem laid with the Google domains account. Apparently, due to a bug on their side, my account was blocked as not being activated. Once the customer service agent fixed that, everything worked smoothly. As such, I think this question's layout can be used to successfully set up a DDNS behind another DDNS and support dynamic domains/subdomains without owning a static IP.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a really old question but I was in a similar situation as I have a dynamic public IP. I just use multiple instances of duckdns which point  to 10 different sub-domains for different services running on my server.

I use Lets-encrypt to handle reverse proxy and ssl certificates and am able to use different sub domains such as a.duckdns.org, b.duckdns.org point to the relevant IP:Port.

The only port forwarding done on the router is to point the ssl port to letsencrypt. I wouldnt advise opening up extra ports unnecessarily.

This is a sample letsencrypt .conf for a music server accessible at a.duckdns.org

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name abcsonic.*; #(Your subdomain/cname)
    include /config/nginx/ssl.conf;
    client_max_body_size 0;
    # enable for ldap auth, fill in ldap details in ldap.conf
    #include /config/nginx/ldap.conf;

    location / {
        # enable the next two lines for http auth
        #auth_basic "Restricted";
        #auth_basic_user_file /config/nginx/.htpasswd;
        # enable the next two lines for ldap auth
        #auth_request /auth;
        #error_page 401 =200 /login;
        include /config/nginx/proxy.conf;
        resolver 127.0.0.11 valid=30s;
        set $upstream_airsonic airsonic;
        proxy_pass http://192.168.10.100:4040; #(Airsonic IP address)
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I actually have a solution for this now :) I have an nginx relay with automaitc letsencrypt in front of it. So, only ports 80 and 443 open, for that. Plus, I have a DDNS client/server pair running alongside, with port 53, to allow for sub-sub domains. Also, wildcard DNS for the main doamin, which means any dubdomain can be hosted with dynamic IP.